# Questions regarding void and pointer

Tags: c

I am currently learning c language. However, I have a bit confuse with the code below:

> void (*fn_test)(void *pData);

Comment: Is there a question here? Which parts do you not understand? Is there more to the code block?
Please specify your actual question(s).

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question. Function pointer syntax is very unclear the first time you see it. The first answer does a good job of answering this IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function pointer. The variable `fn_test` is a pointer to a function which takes a single `void *` argument and returns no value.

In other words, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myFn(void *x) {
    printf("%p\n", x);
}

int main(void){
    int a = 10;
    void (*fn_test)(void*);
    fn_test = myFn;
    fn_test(&a); // Calls myFn
}
```

If you want to understand things like this, you can use the `cdecl` tool, available on many distros and almost certainly downloadable for Windows as well:

```
cdecl> explain void (*fn_test)(void*)
declare fn_test as pointer to function (pointer to void) returning void
```

Or use the online version [here](https://cdecl.org/).

Comment: https://cdecl.org/